# How do I run diagnostics on an iPad Pro 11 with nonfunctioning screen and touch?

Tags: ipad, ipados, tethering, mobile-device-management

I have an 1st generation iPad Pro 11 with a broken screen with no video image and unresponsive to touching. I would like to run some hardware diagnostics on it before committing to replacing the screen.

So far, I've managed to successfully clean and reinstall iPadOS 14.2 by tethering it to my MacBook Pro using a USB cable. I'm able to see the initial iOS setup screen via QuickTime, but can't proceed any further without a functioning touch screen.

Is there an alternative input device I can use? Also, is there any diagnostic mode or software utility available for testing the device's hardware?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's no diagnostic tool.

You *could* hook up a KB/M as well as your MacBook (for display) using a USB-C dongle, but I'm not sure if it'll work.